# How to raise error intentionally with express

Tags: javascript, express, axios

After sending an axios request to my Node server, how can I respond where I "reject" the Axios route/request and end up in the "catch()" of my client side code? I know "res.send(data)" or "res.json(data)" will resolve into "then()" of the promise. Is there anything I can respond with that will reject it?

```
axios.post('/edit-item', {_id: id, updateText: editInput.value, author: author}).then((response) => {
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[3].innerHTML = `${response.data}`
}).catch(() => {
    //I want to end up here by responding with something from the server
})
```

Comment: Any HTTP _error_ status code?

Comment: You can also explicitly _say_ which HTTP status codes you want to consider an error, https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

Comment: Would responding like this- "res.send(404)" reject the promise?

Comment: I want to make it clear that I am intentionally trying to throw an error. As you can see, I am sending over data to my express server. And if the "author" field doesn't match a certain piece of data I want the promise to reject and end up in "catch()" of the "axios.get()" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can raise an error in Node.js which will be handled by the internal error handler, or you may return the status code of your choice

**Raising an error:**

```
app.post(req, res, next) {
  throw new Error('Something went wrong')
```

**Returning error message:**

```
app.post(req, res, next) {
  res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something failed!' })
}
```

instead of `500` you can enter any error status code there

Once you return an error code, axios will go into the `catch` section

You can find more about error handling here: [error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

Return anything with http status code not in range `status >= 200 && status < 300` from your server will get you in the `.catch` block by default:

```
  // `validateStatus` defines whether to resolve or reject the promise for a given
  // HTTP response status code. If `validateStatus` returns `true` (or is set to `null`
  // or `undefined`), the promise will be resolved; otherwise, the promise will be
  // rejected.
  validateStatus: function (status) {
    return status >= 200 && status < 300; // default
  }
```

https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

You can override `validateStatus` to define in which cases the `axios Promise` is `resolved/rejected`